# NSIS Invalid command: IDOK/IDCANCEL

Tags: nsis

I am able to use `MessageBox` `MB_OK` and `MB_OKCANCEL`, but compiler throws an error when I try to use `IDOK` and `IDCANCEL`.

My NSIS version is 2.46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax for calling `MessageBox` with OK and Cancel buttons is:

```
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "my message" IDOK label_for_ok IDCANCEL label_for_cancel
label_for_ok:
;do some stuff
goto end_label ;for not executing the "cancel" branch

label_for_cancel:
;do some other stuff
end_label:
```

In this case, as the ok case is just after the `Messagebox`, you can remove the `IDOK label_for_ok` and the label at the following line.

Comment: ah. Sorry about that. I think I could use a break :)  I was looking at this [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new) and I forgot about the '\'. I was writing it on a newline, which doesn't work.

Comment: oops, the goto is actually not a comment, I have fixed my sample code

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for this little self promo)

You can use my tool called **Visual & Installer** (http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/visual-installer/) to check correct syntax and usage in NSIS script in Visual Studio to avoid such situations:

[image: Visual & Installer]

As you can see it has a really nice syntax highlighting, when you move over some command a tooltip is shown and (if you look at Error List) you can see the PROGRAM_NAME was recognized as unused because it was not defined in the script snippet.